# Sysfs to export device attributes

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel

I've successfully added a device attribute to my device driver, but in all the examples that I found the attribute is used to inject data to the kernel, while my goal would be to export some data from kernel to make it visible in user space. Which is the right way to write to that file from kernel-space? So that data can be retrieved from user-space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read data from the kernel, just return it in the `show` handler:

```c
static ssize_t show_myvalue(struct device *dev,
                            struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf)
{
        struct my_device *mydev = ...dev...;
        return sprintf(buf, "%d\n", mydev->myvalue);
}

static DEVICE_ATTR(myvalue, S_IRUGO, show_myvalue, NULL);
```

If you must notify user space of changes, use `sysfs_notify`.

Comment: Thank you! This definitely worked. If I can ask you, assuming that the process in userspace needs to do a continuous "polling" of these values, is this the most efficient way to send data to userspace?

Comment: This is called whenever userspace calls `read()`. For how to allow userspace to wait for changes, see the last sentence of the answer.

Comment: I think `sysfs_notify` allows `poll/select`.  Another mechanism is `kobject_uevent` and the like.  Ie, use *netlink* and possibly a *udev/mdev* script.